# Replacing an ssd on a notebook

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, backup, ssd

I'm finally running out of space on a 128GB ssd on a notebook (asus N501VW) and am thinking of replacing it with a larger, 500GB, drive.

The setup:

- 1 notebook (N501VW) running Win 10 (x64)
- 3 drives (128GB ssd (M2) (C:), 1TB hdd (D:), 500GB ssd (M2))

**128GB:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsInfo ntfsInfo C:\
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x246467166466ea4e
NTFS Version   :                   3.1
LFS Version    :                   2.0
Number Sectors :                   0x000000000ec25e12
Total Clusters :                   0x0000000001d84bc2
Free Clusters  :                   0x000000000012ce83
Total Reserved :                   0x00000000000450b8
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        512
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            0x0000000036840000
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x00000000005404a0
Mft Zone End   :                   0x0000000000540760
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     512
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0xffffffff
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :      8A0D0FB6-C261-11E6-8455-9CEBE8321CA9
```

**1TB:**

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil fsInfo ntfsInfo D:\
NTFS Volume Serial Number :        0x38f0efcbf0ef8e06
NTFS Version   :                   3.1
LFS Version    :                   2.0
Number Sectors :                   0x0000000074705fff
Total Clusters :                   0x000000000e8e0bff
Free Clusters  :                   0x000000000497daa5
Total Reserved :                   0x00000000000013ff
Bytes Per Sector  :                512
Bytes Per Physical Sector :        4096
Bytes Per Cluster :                4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    :  1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment :  0
Mft Valid Data Length :            0x0000000099940000
Mft Start Lcn  :                   0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                   0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                   0x0000000009a85600
Mft Zone End   :                   0x0000000009a8fd40
Max Device Trim Extent Count :     0
Max Device Trim Byte Count :       0x0
Max Volume Trim Extent Count :     62
Max Volume Trim Byte Count :       0x40000000
Resource Manager Identifier :      14ED2385-C262-11E6-A546-9CEBE8321CA9
```

**500GB:**

```
not purchased as of yet
```

The plan:

1. Boot from a Linux (e.g. ubuntu) usb image
2. Copy C:\ into D:\ (D:\ still has space)
3. Shutdown, replace C:\ with larger ssd
4. Boot (again) from usb
5. Copy C:\ from D:\ into larger ssd
6. Shutdown; boot from larger ssd
7. If all's well, clear former C:\ from D:\

The bad:

1. Will a [dd](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning) format the new ssd entirely upon copy (from D:\ to **500GB**)?
2. If not how much of **500GB** will be usable?
3. Since **128GB** is small, there are many simlinks to D:\ . Will they be affected upon copy?
4. Is this even the right way of doing this?

Comment: There are other tools that probably are better for such task. For example [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).

Comment: The free Macrium Reflect allows copying a running Windows System. This avoids the unbarably slow large copies under Ubuntu. Different size disks are handled properly.

Answer (score 3):

1. No. It will not format your new ssd properly. You will need to resize the partition on the new drive. The partition table will also probably be a little messed up but a utility like gparted should be able to easily fix it.
2. Only 128GB will be available until you resize the partition.
3. I dont see why this would be a problem.
4. It seems reasonable to me. I did the exact same thing to replace a hard drive with an ssd.

Comment: `dd` does "format" drives, in the sense that it clones the entire disk and **all** it's properties. I can't say how it performs for windows partitions as I've never tried to dd one.

Comment: I'll give it a try and see how it goes

Comment: dd does not "format" per see . It allows  reading from one source and writing to another. If you read from /dev/zero it will behave as format writing zeroes to a destination